# RegEx capture the first £ and numbers stop when space or non number

Tags: regex

I am trying to match a monetary amount.

Here is the content:

> Salary, benefits and training package:
>   On the job training will be provided, as Developers will be involved in every aspect of the job. Benefits include a brand new coffee machine, a terrific team to work with, and a relaxed and informal environment.
>   Salary is paying up to £60,000 dependent upon experience.
>   Immediate start on offer..

I want the regex to match `£60,000`.

Can someone help please?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use this regex:

```
£\d+[.,\d]*
```

#### [Working Demo](http://regex101.com/r/sU4hJ4)